# How can I change SQL Agent Log file to use unicode format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logs, sql-server-agent

I've created a database with tables that heavily leverages nvarchar for most of the columns.  One of the challenges I'm running into is that when I go to view the SQL Server Agent Log files, I get the following error noted below.  I've been scouring Google and haven't been able to find anything that closely resembles the scenario I'm experiencing.  Short of re-installing the entire server (which is really isn't an option at this point), how can I flip some sort of switch to make the log files readable again?

(Sorry don't have enough rep here to post an image.  Here's the link to the image.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW7hw.png

Here's the details behind it:

> ===================================
>
> The log file is not using Unicode format. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ---
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=22004&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Server Name: 
>   Error Number: 22004
>   Severity: 16
>   State: 1
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LogSourceSqlAgent.InitializeInternal()
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LogSourceSqlAgent.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.ILogSource.Initialize()
>     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LogSourceAggregation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.ILogSource.Initialize()

Comment: You may have the option "Write OEM file" enabled in your SQL Server Agent properties. Not sure, but can be something to check.

Comment: It is enabled but it's a greyed out box that's checked.

Comment: Where are you seeing it? In the individual file or in the SQL Server Agent properties window? You should be able to change it in the latter.

Comment: My Bad. I missed it and did indeed uncheck the correct box. Everything works as it's supposed to now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@spaghettidba's solution worked for this matter.  By unchecking the 'Write OEM error log' check box (cycled the server as well) by right clicking 'Error Logs' under (servername) -> SQL Server Agent -> Error Logs (in the SQL Server Management Studio) the logs started writing and were readable again.

Comment: I'm curious -- how was this setting enabled in the first place? As far as I can tell, it's not turned on by default.

Comment: I didn't touch any of these settings out of the box.  The only things I modified were settings to add a certificate for server/client encryption to/from box. That's it.

Comment: Interesting. Was the install done on a non-English/US Windows instance, and what was the database engine collation set to?

Comment: It's a standard US version of Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.  The Collation (again, out of the box) is set to 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'.

Comment: Totally bizarre. If you use a standard set of server setup scripts, it might be a good idea to explicitly disable this option just in case.