# SQL Server 2012 SQL Log "the log file is not using Unicode format":

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

On only one server of many, the SQL log is blank and shows a message "the log file is not using Unicode Format" when viewed via SSMS. The log is in the right location as specified in the service properties and is readable with notepad. Log looks normal, just won't show up in Log File Viewer in SSMS. Any ideas why?

SQL Server 2012 in active passive Windows failover cluster on Windows 2012. SQL Server ver 11.0.3368

This instance is the SQL Server for MS SCCM. It has trace flags -T8295 and -T4199 as service startup parms. These were added by SCCM when its DB's were installed.

Thanks

Comment: I had an idea which worked. I forced creation of a new log using sp_cycle_errorlog and the new log can be read fine in SSMS.

This server recently had a bad crash due to a SAN connection failure. I think that the SQL log file may have bcome corrupted as a result of that.

Comment: Any chance you (or someone) opened it up in notepad and then saved it with the wrong format? If the SQL Server service was stopped and restarted as a result of this crash, the error log should have cycled anyway...

Comment: Aaron, thanks. No it had not been saved by anyone. I had tried restarting the instance and a new log was not created. Interestingly, the log from the restart was just appended to the current log.

Comment: Is the "Write OEM error log" option selected?

Comment: Seems like this solution will work (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34422/8783) which @MartinSmith has pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see the "write OEM error log" option is only available for the SQL Agent log. This problem was with the SQL Server log and was resolved by forcing the eror log to be cycled via sp_cycle_error_log

Answer (score 3):

I had an idea which worked. I forced creation of a new log using sp_cycle_errorlog and the new log can be read fine in SSMS. This server recently had a bad crash due to a SAN connection failure. I think that the SQL log file may have bcome corrupted as a result of that.

Answer (score -1):

Simply try to use:

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_cycle_errorlog`

After the new log file is created, it will be visible and readable.

Comment: Did you see the other answer from 10 years ago? It says exactly the same thing, so your answer doesn't seem to add anything.